# I'm having problems with React Typescript compilation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

This has been a massive thorn in my side for far too long now, and it's putting a damper on my ability to learn. I'm attempting to read a fake API from JSONPlaceholder, just to teach myself how APIs work. But I'm currently having trouble even getting my typescript to compile.

First of all, my code is compiling in both .js and .jsx formats, and neither are compiling to the dist folder. I first attempted to compile all typescript files by executing "tsc". It was only after attempting to compile index.js specifically that I got any errors. Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

This is my file structure after compilation:

[image]

As it stands, compiling my code returns many errors that I cannot understand, and seem to be referring to files outside of my code. I'm getting so many that VSCode won't let me scroll back far enough to see the first error returned. Here are the last four. The last error, in particular, is a problem I've been unable to get past since I started learning typescript. I get this error both when no export should be expected and when the .tsx file DOES have a default export:

```
../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3288:13
    3288             view: React.SVGProps<SVGViewElement>;
                     ~~~~
    'view' was also declared here.

../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3100:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 
'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

3100         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3097:14
    3097         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.

index.tsx:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"C:/Users/aaron/OneDrive/Desktop/API Practice/api-practice-frontend/node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

1 import React from 'react';
         ~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:65:1
    65 export = React;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

index.tsx:2:8 - error TS1192: Module '"C:/Users/aaron/OneDrive/Desktop/API Practice/api-practice-frontend/node_modules/@types/react-dom/index"' has no default export.    

2 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Below is all of my relevant code. Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here so I can get past this problem. As long as I'm stuck trying to understand how to make typescript compile correctly, I'm not going to get anything else done. Thanks in advance.

App.tsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

interface Comment {
  postId: number
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
  body: string
}

function App() {
  const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState<Comment[]>([])

  const getComments = async () => {
    const data = await (await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments')).json()
    let comments: Comment[] = []
    for (let comment of data){
      comments.push(comment)
    }
    setPosts(comments)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={getComments}>Get Comments</button>
      {posts[0] && posts.map(post => <p>{post}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Compiled App.jsx:

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
exports.__esModule = true;
var react_1 = require("react");
require("./App.css");
function App() {
    var _this = this;
    var _a = react_1.useState([]), posts = _a[0], setPosts = _a[1];
    var getComments = function () { return __awaiter(_this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var data, comments, _i, data_1, comment;
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            switch (_a.label) {
                case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments')];
                case 1: return [4 /*yield*/, (_a.sent()).json()];
                case 2:
                    data = _a.sent();
                    comments = [];
                    for (_i = 0, data_1 = data; _i < data_1.length; _i++) {
                        comment = data_1[_i];
                        comments.push(comment);
                    }
                    setPosts(comments);
                    return [2 /*return*/];
            }
        });
    }); };
    return (<div className="App">
      <button onClick={getComments}>Get Comments</button>
      {posts[0] && posts.map(function (post) { return <p>{post}</p>; })}
    </div>);
}
exports["default"] = App;
```

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './dist/index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Compiled index.js:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var react_1 = require("react");
var react_dom_1 = require("react-dom");
require("./dist/index.css");
var App_1 = require("./App");
react_dom_1["default"].render(<react_1["default"].StrictMode>
    <App_1["default"] />
  </react_1["default"].StrictMode>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "api-practice-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The error says you need to add `"esModuleInterop": true,` to the `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: `tsc` isn't very good at compiling front end applications. This is what bundlers like webpack, parcel, etc are for. These tools bundle the code into small amounts of large files so a browser doesn't need to request hundreds (or possibly thousands) of javascript files when a page loads. I would _highly_ recommend you start with https://create-react-app.dev/ if you're just starting out as it handles all this plumbing for you.

Comment: @smac89 It's already there, though. I have my tsconfig listed above.

Comment: @Alex Wayne So, just use "npx create-react-app.dev" instead of "npm create-react-app" when creating a new project?

Comment: No that's just a link to the website. I won't be able to improve on the documentation _on_ that website, though, which shows you how to get started. You may even be able to just copy the code you have into that container and have it work.

Comment: I would recommend you to simply recreate the app, so you do not need to deal with building and learning webpack etc. When creating a ts react app you can just run `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't allowJs.
Also, the target should be es6 or es2021.

The below should be a reference. It should work

```
  "incremental": true,
  "target": "es2021",
  "lib": ["dom", "es2021"],
  "jsx": "react-jsx",
  "module": "ES6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true
```

Also, if you want to build, remember to `npx tsc` before `npm run build`